# place <Text> at middle and left end

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-native

I have a screen where I want to place the first, main text item `(Filter)`in the exact **middle of the screen** while the second item `(All Delete)` should be at the **right end**. Both of them should be in the same line.

I would prefer not to use padding/margins since they can vary in different phone sizes. I am already using text-align but it doesn't work for me.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
       <View style={styles.topTextContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.filterText}>Filter</Text>
            <Text style={styles.deleteAllText}>All Delete</Text>
          </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
},
  topTextContainer: {
    paddingTop: moderateScale(35),
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  filterText: {
    fontSize: moderateScale(15),
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
  deleteAllText: {
    fontSize: moderateScale(13),
    color: '#363636',
    fontWeight: '300',
    marginLeft: moderateScale(75),
  },
});
```

Codesandbox: https://snack.expo.io/@nhammad/frowning-bagel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a absolute position for the delete button and set right:0 like below.

```
deleteAllText: {
    fontSize: moderateScale(13),
    color: '#363636',
    fontWeight: '300',
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 0
  }
```

The other option is to use `marginLeft:'auto'` for the both the texts which can help but wont keep the first one in center.

Comment: somehow this works on the codesandbox but not in my app. Over there, it drags all delete text to the upper or lower line.

Comment: Does the app have any other components in the screen ?

Comment: @Jnl when you use absolute it goes to the top, as you are having a padding top in the parent you will have to set the top:35 along with right:0

Answer (score 0):

With exact milld do you mean in the middle of the screen width and height like this:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  topTextContainer: {
    paddingTop: moderateScale(35),
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: "100%"
  },
  filterText: {
    fontSize: moderateScale(15),
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
  deleteAllText: {
    fontSize: moderateScale(13),
    color: '#363636',
    fontWeight: '300',
    position: "absolute",
    right: 0
    //marginLeft: moderateScale(75),
  },
});
```

If yes, you should set the `height: "100%"`

if you want to have it on the top middle than this should be the right approach:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  topTextContainer: {
    paddingTop: moderateScale(35),
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  filterText: {
    fontSize: moderateScale(15),
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
  deleteAllText: {
    fontSize: moderateScale(13),
    color: '#363636',
    fontWeight: '300',
    position: "absolute",
    right: 0
    //marginLeft: moderateScale(75),
  },
});
```

setting `deleteAllText` `position: absolute` and `right: 0`